# Mouse cursor always visible in game

Tags: pc, technical-issues, dark-souls

I just started to play Dark Souls on PC and I noticed that the cursor remains visible during the game. Although I can play with it I find it really annoying to always have a white thingy jumping through my screen when there isn't supposed to be one.

I did some research but I couldn't find anything promising since most of the programs that promise to fix this bug don't seem to be very trustworthy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally people use [Dark Souls Mouse Fix](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls/mods/28/?) (often called DSMfix) to fix the mouse issues with the game. It's best used in combination with [DSfix](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls/mods/19/?), which includes general fixes to make the PC version work better on most PCs and allow more options.

Comment: Here's to hoping that we will have *absolutely none* of these ridiculous problems in the DSII PC release.

Comment: note that you need this DSMfix update for the newest Dark Souls patch: http://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/864979455329386779/

Answer (score 2):

While 3ventic offered a good fix for the problem, I'd also suggest just buying a cheap USB controller from Gamestop or something. The game is a direct port and is meant to be played with a controller so aside from multiple downloads / tweaks, the game will play like garbage with a keyboard and mouse.

I've been a PC gamer for over 15 years and Dark Souls / Castle Crashers are among a number games that really do play better with a controller even if you've never used a recent console's controller. There are few games I'd actually recommend using a controller on PC for, but this is certainly one of them.

Although if you insist on using a keyboard and mouse for the game, refer to 3Ventic's answer. Also for what it's worth, most Steam games that need tweaking or have port (or normal) issues such as this one you described usually have an answer or a few trusted recommended fixes over at the official Steam forums for that game.

I've on several occasions had to get fixes for mouse / keyboard / other misc in-game issues over there and chances are someone has already asked the same question as you and possibly received an answer!

Hope this helps!

Edit: After some research, I found that DSFix is pretty hit or miss depending on your system and settings, but it is pretty much your best bet to hide the cursor even when using a controller.

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900179

Also for a comprehensive list of issues / fixes take a look at 
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900321

Comment: Does using a controller eliminate the visible mouse without DSFix?

Comment: Hmm, it appears not. http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900179

Should I delete my answer since it's only partially correct?

Comment: this information is ***perfect*** for a comment on the question *or* include DSFix as the answer, and recommend using a controller additionally. I completely agree about a controller being almost necessary for DS and the information you gave is great. Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: @Mondrianaire Thanks for the advice.  I edited it to more appropriately answer the question as well as give advice.

Answer (score 0):

I simply moved the cursor off the edge of the screen to hide it. I have a second monitor, but even without it the cursor should be hidden on the right side of the screen. If you play with a controller, that's all you need to do.

If you play with keyboard/mouse then it probably won't work. You can still move the cursor onto the second monitor (if you have one) and your character will still react to the mouse movement, but as soon as you click, Dark Souls app will lose focus. Try to remap the click keybindings to keyboard in this case (if it is even possible).